# Exercise V.1.5. Hartshorne

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, intersection-theory

1. Let $X$ be a surface of degree $d$ in $\mathbb P^3_K$, we compute $K_X^2$. We have $S\sim dH$ and $K_{\mathbb P^3}\sim -4H$ for a hyper plane $H$. We have by Hartshorne II.8.20 that
   $$\omega_X\cong \omega_{\mathbb P^3}\otimes \mathcal O_{\mathbb P^3}(X)\otimes \mathcal O_X\cong \mathcal O_{\mathbb P^3}(d-4)|_{X}$$
   So $K_X\sim (d-4)H|_{X}$ to my understanding. The idea to compute $K_X^2$ is to say that
   $$K_X^2=(d-4)H\cdot (d-4)H=(d-4)^2H^2=d(d-4)^2$$
   So first why do we have $H^2=d$ ? And more importantly, why isn't the restriction $H|_X$ a problem to compute the intersection number ? I would totally agree if we had $K_X\sim (d-4)H$ but I don't think this is quite true, even with the adjunction formula from Beauville we restrict to the curve.

2. Now consider $X=C\times C'$ curves with genus $g,g'$ respectively. We have that $K_X=p_1^*K_C+p_2^*K_{C'}$ with projections $p_1,p_2$. So we have directly that
   $$K_X^2=p_1^*K_C^2+2p_1^*K_C\cdot p_2^*K_{C'}+p_2^*K_{C'}$$
   So here I saw left and right terms vanish so there is only the middle term.
   From now on I get confused, $p_1^*K_C$ is a curve, so I want to apply the adjunction formula, but what is it's genus ? Is it $g$?

Supposing this is true, and by applying adjunction formula to $p_1^*K_C,p_2^*K_{C'}$ I get
$$p_1^*K_C^2+p_1^*K_C\cdot p_2^*K_{C'}=2g-2,\quad p_2^*K_{C'} ^2 +p_1^*K_C\cdot p_2^*K_{C'}^2=2g'-2$$
By substracting one by the other we get that $p_1^*K_C^2-p_2^*K_{C'}=2g-2g'$ which is not necessarily zero, but should be from what I saw so there is a problem.

So how can we get the genus of a pullback and how can we compute this kind of intersection product ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. People frequently write $H$ when they mean $H|_X$, which is probably the source of part of your confusion. To compute $H|_X^2$, one strategy you can use is from the end of problem V.1.2: if $D$ is a very ample divisor on a surface $X$ and $C$ is a curve on $X$, then the intersection product $D.C$ is the degree of the curve $C$ under the embedding $X\hookrightarrow \Bbb P^N$ determined by $D$. (Sketch: since all the linearly equivalent representatives of $D$ correspond to hyperplanes in $\Bbb P^N$, pick a good representative which intersects $C$ nicely, apply proposition V.1.4 which says $C.D=\sum_{P\in C\cap D} i(C,D;P)$ if $C,D$ are curves with no common component, and recognize that this is also the degree of $C\cap H$ by Bezout's theorem.) As the embedding induced by $H$ is the already-supplied embedding in $\Bbb P^3$, you're now asking for the degree of a hyperplane section of a degree $d$ surface in $\Bbb P^3$. By Bezout, this is $d$.
2. There's no need to apply the adjunction formula to compute $(p^*K_C)^2$. Instead, you can just find two representatives which don't intersect and apply proposition V.1.4 again. If $C$ is $\Bbb P^1$, then $K_C\sim -P-Q$ for any two points $P,Q\in\Bbb P^1$, so $p^*K_C\sim -[C'\times\{P\}]-[C'\times\{Q\}]$ for any choice of $P,Q\in\Bbb P^1$, and intersecting two representatives with no points in common gives an intersection product of 0 (again by proposition V.1.4). If $C$ is a different smooth curve, then by [an answer to one of your previous questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4781957/kodaira-dimension-on-curve-is-0-implies-elliptic-curve/4782014#4782014), $K_C$ is base-point free, so we can find two representatives of $K_C$ which have no points in common. Then we can do the same thing - write $p^*K_C\sim C'\times S_1$ and $p^*K_C\sim C'\times S_2$, where $S_1$ and $S_2$ are two finite sets of disjoint closed points in $C$, and then apply proposition V.1.4 to get that $(p^*K_C)^2=0$ since those divisors don't intersect. To compute the final answer to this portion of the exercise, use that the center term is the intersection of a bunch of vertical and horizontal fibers (so the intersections are transversal) and count the number of intersection points.

Answer (score 0):

Since $H$ is the class of the plane, $H^2$ is the class of the intersection of $2$ general planes, i.e. the class of a line. Depending on how you define things, it is more or less tautological that a general line and a degree $d$ surface in $\mathbb P^3$ intersect in $d$ reduced points.

Intersection products like $(p_i^*(K_C))^2$ can be thought of as pulled back from the base curve; since divisors on curves intersect trivially, this is always $0$. You can also think of it this way: choose $2$ disjoint canonical divisors on $C$ and pull them back to $C \times C'$. These pullbacks are each unions of fibers isomorphic to $C'$, and there are no fibers in common between the two, so the intersection is $0$.

Comment: So it's tautological, great. I didn't define anything, in Hartshorne the self intersection product of a curve $C$ in a surface $S$ is defined to be $\deg_C(\mathcal O_S(C)\otimes \mathcal O_C)$. Why is this being $d$ tautological ? Moreover we still have the question that you omitted. To my understanding $H$ is not a curve, it's a hyperplane in $P^3$ so what you're talking about doesn't exist if I push my reasoning. Unless of course we restrict $H|_X$. I can understand your intuitive explanation for 2), but can't we just directly compute this ?